Windows 11 Media Creation Tool, error 0x8007010B 0xA0003. What can I do?
pic
The process fails during media creation, the download completes successfully
The flash drive I'm using is 16 GB, blank, fat32.
What could possibly be the problem? Already tried this on 2 different computers, same result.
Please don't suggest me to use Rufus, before resorting to unofficial means I want to try the official Microsoft route in any way possible.

Post the log from the Setup Diagnostic application by Microsoft this will indicate the reason the installation failed. You likely have an application that is blocking the installation of 24H2. Impossible to diagnose the error code without that log

In the end, it worked after trying again but it took a long time, thanks everyone.

If you distrust Rufus, then I suggest you read this because it's about as official a tool to create Windows installation media as the Microsoft one. The only difference is that one is branded by Microsoft and closed source, whereas the other is 100% Open Source.

Instead of using the Media Creation Tool, download the ISO from
Download Windows 11.
You'll need to go below
"Download Windows 11 Disk Image (ISO) for x64 devices",
select the download version (and perhaps language) and click
"Download Now".
You will find more information in the article
Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade.

The error code the author received is caused by an application that is installed that has been flagged as incompatible with 24H2. There is a log the author can provide which can be used to diagnose which application that is, I suspect I know which application it is, but I cannot determine if I am right since the question does not contain that vital information

no, the media is for 23h2, microsoft is not yet distributing 24h2 right now, because it hasnt been released yet on the standard ring, only on the preview one
